# Como exibir elementos de tamanhos específicos pertencentes a uma lista com auxílio das funções lambda e filter?

Tags: python, expressões-lambda, filter

Nesse código que escrevi:

```
lstNomes = ["casa", "google", "escola"]

lstFiltro = list(filter(lambda x: x <= "5", lstNomes))
```

Está retornando o array vazio:

```
[]
```

Queria saber como consigo o elemento dentro da lstNomes com comprimento menor ou igual a 5.

Comment: Alteração feita!

Comment: Obrigado. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver esta questão, basta utilizar o seguinte código:

```
lstNomes = ["casa", "google", "escola"]

lstFiltro = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 5, lstNomes))
print(lstFiltro)
```

**Observação 1:**

Como desejas capturar as palavras de tamanho **menores ou iguais a 5** e, como os elementos da lista são **strings**, você deve verificar o tamanho de cada elemento iterado, para em seguida exibi-los.

**Observação 2:**

Neste caso foi exibido **apenas 1** resultado. Pois, neste caso, só temos uma palavra de tamanho menor ou igual a **5**.

Agora, se, nesta lista existisse outras palavras de tamanhos menores ou iguais a **5**, todas elas seriam exibidas.